# How to avoid code duplication to use while loop effectively?

Tags: python

```
pizzaq = 2.50
riceq = 7.89

rs = ['r', 'ri', 'ric', 'rice', 'R', 'Ri', 'Ric', 'Rice', 'ice', 'ic', 'rce']
bs = ['p', 'pi', 'piz', 'pizz', 'pizza', 'P', 'Pi','Piz', 'Pizz', 'Pizza']

c = input("What is your name? ")
d = input("Hello " + c + ", what you like to order today? \n Rice or Pizza? ")
e = input("How many packets? ")
q = 0
if d in rs:
    q = int(e) * riceq
    print(c + "'s order for Rice is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
    print("Please make the payment!")
elif d in bs:
    q = int(e) * pizzaq
    print(c + "'s order for Pizza is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
    print("Please make the payment!")
else:
    pass

while q == 0:
    # main program
    op1 = ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'Y']
    op2 = ['no', 'n', 'No', 'N']
    qu = input("We don't have "+ "'" + d + "'" + " Would you like to try again? ")
    if qu in op1:
        c = input("What is your name? ")
        d = input("Hello " + c + ", what you like to order today? \n Rice or Pizza? ")
        e = input("How many packets? ")
        if d in rs:
            q = int(e) * riceq
            print(c + "'s order for Rice is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
            print("Please make the payment!")
        elif d in bs:
            q = int(e) * pizzaq
            print(c + "'s order for Pizza is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
            print("Please make the payment!")
    elif qu in op2:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

I was trying to find a way to make the loop part more compact or avoid the duplication of it again in the while loop. Can anybody suggest a better way to organize this code and how can I make this an independent program to run in Windows operating system.

Comment: https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/ I can suggest you to use pyinstaller, to turn your program into an executable .exe file.

Comment: I tried it and the compiled program started and exited after executing the first two lines of code!

Answer (score 1):

you can directly start with the loop,

```
pizzaq = 2.50
riceq = 7.89

rs = ['r', 'ri', 'ric', 'rice', 'R', 'Ri', 'Ric', 'Rice', 'ice', 'ic', 'rce']
bs = ['p', 'pi', 'piz', 'pizz', 'pizza', 'P', 'Pi','Piz', 'Pizz', 'Pizza']
op1 = ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'Y']
op2 = ['no', 'n', 'No', 'N']

q=0 #no need of this if using"while True:"
while q == 0: #while True: seems better
    c = input("What is your name? ")
    d = input("Hello " + c + ", what you like to order today? \n Rice or Pizza? ")
    e = input("How many packets? ")
    if d in rs:
        q = int(e) * riceq
        print(c + "'s order for Rice is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
        print("Please make the payment!")
        break
    elif d in bs:
        q = int(e) * pizzaq
        print(c + "'s order for Pizza is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
        print("Please make the payment!")
        break
    else:
        qu = input("We don't have "+ "'" + d + "'" + " Would you like to try again? ")
        if qu in op1:
            continue
        elif qu in op2:
            print("Goodbye")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid copy paste of code, the best is to use functions. You can also call functions from other functions:

```
pizzaq = 2.50
riceq = 7.89
rs = ['r', 'ri', 'ric', 'rice', 'R', 'Ri', 'Ric', 'Rice', 'ice', 'ic', 'rce']
bs = ['p', 'pi', 'piz', 'pizz', 'pizza', 'P', 'Pi','Piz', 'Pizz', 'Pizza']

def get_name_and_order_type():
  c = input("What is your name? ")
  d = input("Hello " + c + ", what you like to order today? \n Rice or Pizza? ")
  e = input("How many packets? ")
  return c,d,e

def ask_for_payment(c, q, food):
  print(f"{c}'s order for {food} is processed and the charges are Rs. {q}")
  print("Please make the payment!")

def process_order():
  q = 0
  c,d,e = get_name_and_order_type()
  if d in rs:
      q = int(e) * riceq
      ask_for_payment(c, q, "Rice")
  elif d in bs:
      q = int(e) * pizzaq
      ask_for_payment(c, q, "Pizza")
  return d,q

d,q = process_order()

while q == 0:
    op1 = ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'Y']
    op2 = ['no', 'n', 'No', 'N']
    qu = input("We don't have "+ "'" + d + "'" + " Would you like to try again? ")
    if qu in op1:
        d,q = process_order()
    elif qu in op2:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to write a separate function for taking the order, and put the main program in a single `while True` loop.

```
products = [
    {"name": "rice", "synonyms": ['r', 'ri', 'ric', 'rice', 'ice', 'ic', 'rce'], "price": 7.89},
    {"name": "pizza", "synonyms": ['p', 'pi', 'piz', 'pizz', 'pizza'], "price": 2.50}
]

def take_order(prompt): 
    names = [product["name"].capitalize() for product in products]
    choice = ", ".join(names[:-1]) + " or " + names[-1]
    order = input(f"{prompt} what you like to order today?\n{choice}? ").lower()
    for product in products:
        if order in product["synonyms"]:
            return product

def main():
    while True:
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        prompt = f"Hello {name},"
        product = take_order(prompt)
        if product is not None:
            quantity = int(input("How many packets? "))
            print(f"{name}'s order for {product['name']} is processed and the charges are Rs. {quantity * product['price']:.2f}")
            print("Please make the payment!")
            return
        else:
            cont = input("We don't have that. Would you like to try again? ").lower()
            if cont in ['no', 'n']:
                print("Goodbye")
                return
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution optimises the processing for the given order options and may not generalise well because it relies on the first letter of the name of the order item for a dictionary key. Alternatively the name of the order item could be used for the key.

```
def greet_and_take_order():
    name = input("What is your name? ").strip()
    order = input(f"Hello {name}, what you like to order today? \n Rice or Pizza? ").strip()
    amount = input("How many packets? ").strip()
    return (name, order, amount)

def request_payment(name, cost, food):
    print(f"{name}'s order for {food} is processed and the charges are Rs. {cost}")
    print("Please make the payment!")

def process_order():
    food_options = {
      "P": ("Pizza", 2.50),
      "R": ("Rice", 7.89)
    }
    # Order has not been processed
    processed = False
    name, order, amount = greet_and_take_order()
    # Take the first letter from the `order` string and capitalise it
    order_key = order[0].upper()
    # Is the letter found in the `keys` for the `food_options` dictionary?
    if order_key in food_options.keys():
        item_name, item_cost = food_options[order_key]
        cost = int(amount) * item_cost
        request_payment(name, cost, item_name)
        # Order has been processed
        processed = True
    return (processed, order)

def main_loop():
    state = True
    while state:
        state, order = process_order()
        if not state:
            # An unknown order was placed
            response = input(f"We don't have {order}. Would you like to try again? Yes/No ").strip().upper()
        # Check first letter of `response` string
        if response[0] == 'Y':
            state, order = process_order()
        elif response[0] == 'N':
            print("Goodbye")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_loop()
```

**`if __name__ == '__main__':`**

In Python 3, `__name__` is a variable name that is assigned the value of `__main__` when the current file/module is being executed. Otherwise it contains the name of the script/module if it has been imported into another script which is being executed. Using the conditional check it's possible to ensure that the `main_loop` function is only run when the script is executed, if the file was to be imported into another file it would have to be explicitly called.

**Format strings**

`f"Hello {name}"` is the short way of writing `"Hello {name}".format(name)`.

```
s = "Hello {name}"
name = "Bob"
print(s.format(name))
# 'Hello Bob'
print(f"Hello {name}")
# 'Hello Bob'
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thank you!! It is a bit complex for me at this stage of my learning especially I don't really know how __name__ part is working. Anyway this a copy I can keep it for next lessons in the coming days.

Comment: Do you mean the format string `f"Hello {name}"`?

Comment: No. The last lines  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_loop()

Comment: I just noticed that part as well. Why you are using the 'f' there before the placeholder?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain both for you.

Answer (score -1):

It's seems that you don't need first part - q==0 true after definition

```
pizzaq = 2.50
riceq = 7.89

rs = ['r', 'ri', 'ric', 'rice', 'R', 'Ri', 'Ric', 'Rice', 'ice', 'ic', 'rce']
bs = ['p', 'pi', 'piz', 'pizz', 'pizza', 'P', 'Pi','Piz', 'Pizz', 'Pizza']


q = 0
while q == 0:
    # main program
    op1 = ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'Y']
    op2 = ['no', 'n', 'No', 'N']
    qu = input("We don't have "+ "'" + d + "'" + " Would you like to try again? ")
    if qu in op1:
        c = input("What is your name? ")
        d = input("Hello " + c + ", what you like to order today? \n Rice or Pizza? ")
        e = input("How many packets? ")
        if d in rs:
            q = int(e) * riceq
            print(c + "'s order for Rice is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
            print("Please make the payment!")
        elif d in bs:
            q = int(e) * pizzaq
            print(c + "'s order for Pizza is processed and the charges are ", "Rs.", q)
            print("Please make the payment!")
    elif qu in op2:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```